# How to make this pie chart show how many people selected option 1 and option 2?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

So I have 6 people who entered a choice, 1 is dependant, 2 is no. (Can't post images)

http://puu.sh/sMQvB/8722d3cce2.png

How to make it that so the pie chart displays how many people selected option 1 and option 2? The halfs should be equal based on the table.

http://puu.sh/sMQvS/c57cafc1bc.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel Pie Charts plot the value of categorical values (in your case Dependant/Not).  So you need to start with those values, then add the total number for each category.  So your data table and chart will look something like this (substituted Yes/No for categories):

[image: example]